# Getting row number corresponding to a date AND time in differing columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to get the row number in a pandas df that corresponds to a datetime value of 14/03/2019 and a time of 6:00. My date and time and in different columns, the date is the index and time is in a column called 'time'.

I tried:

```
df.index.get_loc('2019-03-14') and df['time'].get_loc('06:00:00')
```

but I get

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
cheers

Comment: Can you add some sample data, ie.. like five rows of data with the row you want to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
(df.index.date=='2019-03-14')&df.Time.eq('06:00:00')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion!  I tried that and I got the following error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'eq'